# Determining Min/Max values from feature class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, export, csv

I am very rusty/inexperienced in Python.

I would like to create a more compact script that prints min and max values of each numeric field from a feature class. Right now I have the code below repeated for each field that contains numeric values.

How would I code this to identify if a field has numeric values and then print the min and max values to the python shell or even better to a .csv/text file?

```
import arcpy
data = "C:/Workfolder/Input.gdb/FeatureClass"

listname = []
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(data, "field1")

for row in cursor:
    listname.append(int(row[0]))

print 'Field1_min, {0}'.format(min(listname))
print 'Field2_max, {0}'.format(max(listname))
```

Answer (score 6):

I think one of the efficient options would be using `where` and `sql_clause` arguments of `arcpy.da`, for example:

```
field_to_find_min_max = "MyFieldName"
min_value = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(data, field_to_find_min_max, "{} IS NOT NULL".format(field_to_find_min_max), sql_clause = (None, "ORDER BY {} ASC".format(field_to_find_min_max))).next()[0]
max_value = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(data, field_to_find_min_max, "{} IS NOT NULL".format(field_to_find_min_max), sql_clause = (None, "ORDER BY {} DESC".format(field_to_find_min_max))).next()[0]
```

This also makes sure the only non-NULL values are processed (where clause).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to calculate the minimum is to use the [SummaryStatistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) function.

To iterate through the fields, use the [ListFields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000012000000) function:

```
# Create a list of fields using the ListFields function
fields = arcpy.ListFields(feature_class)

# Iterate through the list of fields
for field in fields:
    if(field.type == 'Integer' or field.type == "Double"):
        #calculate the minimum using SummaryStatistics
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the list is clever, or at least it seems until you get to a *very* large feature class. Instead of the list:

```
import arcpy
data = "C:/Workfolder/Input.gdb/FeatureClass"

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(data, "field1")

FirstRecord = True

for row in cursor:
    if FirstRecord:
        FirstRecord = False
        MinValue = int(row[0])
        MaxValue = int(row[0])
    else:
        MinValue = min(int(row[0]),MinValue)
        MaxValue = max(int(row[0]),MaxValue)

print 'Field1_min, {0}'.format(MinValue)
print 'Field2_max, {0}'.format(MaxValue)
```

Or using [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000):

```
import arcpy
data = "C:/Workfolder/Input.gdb/FeatureClass"
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(data,r"c:\WorkFolder\Input.gdb\StatTable",[["Field1","min"],["Field1","max"]])
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r"c:\WorkFolder\Input.gdb\StatTable",["Field1_min","Field1_max"])
row = cursor.next()
print "Field1 Min = %s, Field1 Max = %s" % (str(row[0]), str(row[1]))
del row
del cur
arcpy.Delete_management(r"c:\WorkFolder\Input.gdb\StatTable")
```

Be careful that field1 is, or can be converted to, an integer. If it's a date or string field you're gonna have problems!

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.  This will reclassify the fields in my feature class as integers then? listname.append(int(row[0]))

Comment: It will, if they can be converted to int: short int, long int, double and float can be converted to int. Some text can be converted to int but first you need to check if it can - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python

Comment: @user29499 listname.append(int(row[0])) will reclassify the _value_ of row[0] to integer, but it won't reclassify the _field in the feature class_ as integer

Comment: Good point @StephenLead, it will change the *value* obtained from the field, if it can, but not the field itself. So if the field is a double the value obtained is converted to an int but the field itself remains unchanged - a double. Generally speaking field types can't be changed; there are ways but it's risky and could destroy the data.