# Min and max in a field attribute with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I have a shapefile with a field attribute called `"Value"`.

I would like to find the `min` and `max` in this field and

- if `max-min > 0.014` return `1` (or `Yes`)
- if `max-min < 0.014` then return `2` (or `No`)

in the field called `"YES_NO"`.

[image]

Comment: have you already seen these articles: [Determining Min/Max values from feature class using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101460/determining-min-max-values-from-feature-class-using-arcpy), [arcpy min/max/unique values of a field](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281716/arcpy-min-max-unique-values-of-a-field)?

Comment: So all rows will have yes or all will have no?

Comment: It is unclear. Do you want to know if the difference between two successive rows more or less than 0.014, or just max - min values in the Value field more or less than 0.014? Please explain in your question.

Comment: no, can be completely 1 or completely 2

Comment: in this example the max = 1.1255 and min = 1.0852. max - min = 0.040 so its > 0.014. so the field YES-NO is filled completely by 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the da.SearchCursor to find min, max and diff. Update field with the UpdateCursor:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\featureclass'
fields = ['Value','YES_NO']

all_rows = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields[0])]
min_val = min(all_rows)
max_val = max(all_rows)
difference = max_val-min_val

if difference > 0.014:
    newval = 1
elif difference <= 0.014:
    newval = 2
else:
    newval = 3

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields[1]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = newval
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```